# Highchart: How to calculate the distance between each bar in Bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I need to show all the text in label without ellipsis, But I cannot predict the number of lines that the label will take.

1. Is it possible to give some margin between each label and show
   the bar in center align to label? (with or without varying the
   distance between each bar)
2. Is it possible to calculate the distance between each bar?
3. Is it possible to calculate the number of lines the label will take?

Here I am setting the height of the chart with number of bars in it with a random guess of each label taking 4 lines.

Image is altered, Sometimes it there are labels with single lines & some times multiple lines.

*Example:*

[image: Example image]

Comment: The space between the bars is entirely dependent on **1**) the height of the chart/plot area, **2**) the number of bars, **3**) the width of the bars. All of which you control. Calculating space between bars is just basic math based on those factors. Calculating the number of lines a label will take is significantly more complicated.

Comment: I can attest to the difficulty of knowing how many lines. Our business rules on the HTML are that we can allow ellipses but on export we need to show full text. Lots of work and trial and error and testing went in to coming up with a generic formula that adjusts chart height based upon length of categories. No one-size-fits all algorithm though.

Comment: @jlbriggs: I am calculating the height of the plot area by counting the number of bars, each bar is of fixed 18px. but since I should not show ellipsis. I am taking the above and multiplying with a random number which will give enough space to show 4 lines of label.

Comment: Or use a monospaced font making it really easy to predict the dimensions needed for the text label

Answer (score 0):

This information may be useful in context of the **question 3.** (answers for questions 1 & 2 appeared in the comments below the question):

Dividing a label text to separate lines (in case when `useHTML === false`) is performed in `Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.buildText` function.

In this **live demo** I've overwritten this core function and added `console.log` that prints how many `<tspans>` were generated for a specific line: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/x2619jmv/

It seems that Highcharts may run it multiple times before it finds the proper configuration of the labels.